# How do I Use VBA Macro on Hidden Worksheets. and Hide them back

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in VBA excel Macros. By using this forum i could write a code but i am stuck at one place.

I have  10 sheets in a workbook. 1st Sheet is my input worksheet and does all the calculations. These calculations are pulled in later 9 sheets. These 9 sheets generate my report.In calculation file i want to hide all the next 9 files and run the macro. once the calculations are okay. I click a Generate report button and new file is created and opens on my desktop and get saved in my document.

Problem - Somehow going through this forum i was able to generate a code that does everything but i am not able to get Hide and unhide part.
The code i wrote unhide all the files from calculation file.(Keeps them unhide) and hides the file in newly generated report.(as all files cannot be hidden in any new excel i get run-time error'1004' unable to set the visible property of the worksheet class).

here is my code please help me solve it - So i can have only 1 sheet in calculation file while rest remain hidden when macro works. And newly generated file will have all the 9 tabs.

```
Sub SaveMain()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Cover").Visible = True
Sheets("2").Visible = True
Sheets("3").Visible = True
Sheets("4").Visible = True
Sheets("5").Visible = True
Sheets("6").Visible = True
Sheets("7").Visible = True
Sheets("8").Visible = True
Sheets("9").Visible = True

Dim Flname As String


Flname = "Pump Datasheet" & InputBox("Enter Pump tag No P-XXXX:") & ".xls"

Sheets(Array("Cover", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")).Copy

Sheets("Cover").Visible = False
Sheets("2").Visible = False
Sheets("3").Visible = False
Sheets("4").Visible = False
Sheets("5").Visible = False
Sheets("6").Visible = False
Sheets("7").Visible = False
Sheets("8").Visible = False
Sheets("9").Visible = False

newfilename = Flname

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=50

End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't understand. You want it hidden in which workbook?

Comment: You need at least one sheet visible. In your code, near the end, you set all sheets to hidden. Try setting "Cover" to True.

Comment: My Parent file has (calculation file +9 other sheet). Those 9 sheets are hidden but 9 hidden files take data from calculation file. Once my calculation file is completed I click generate report. It creates NEW FILE which has 9 sheets and doesn't have calculation file anymore. These 9 sheets come from Parent file (I want them all visible in New file but remain hidden in Parent file).
My macro unhides 9 files in parent sheet (which i dont want). and hides file in newly generated file (again which i dont want). So it does reverse of both i want.

Comment: You switch between saying 'sheets' and 'files'... which is is please? After your code runs to Unhide, then hide, you never save the original workbook again -- you do a SaveAs -- which creates a new Workbook. Easy part first: in your above code, get rid of all the the ....Visible = False lines of code. That will result in your new workbook sheets being visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding and unhiding your sheets like this, it will save you a lot of energy if needing to change later.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'To unhide all sheets
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next

'To hide all sheets except "Cover"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Cover" Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try to implement it.

Comment: Is there anyway I can keep 2 sheets Visible.  few diffrent try didnt help.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Calculations" And "Sheet1" Then
     ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

Error: says type mismatch

I also Tried 

     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
     ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden


Error : control Variable already in use. 
Can you please help ?
I also have my program in comment box at the bottom

Comment: Yeah, you can either do it by sheet index or sheet name. But it would look like this `If ws.name <> "Cover" and ws.name <> "Other Name" Then` or you could use `If ws.Index <> 1 and ws.index <> 2 Then`. But when you use an AND / OR logic modifier, you have to make a complete statement again.

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest you tweak this to ensure that *Cover* exists first.

If so the loop to hide the sheets can be set more directly - doesn't actually need a *Then* test.

```
Sub Sheeted()
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets("Cover")
On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Visible = (ws.Name = "Cover")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's cool! Using a comparison where a boolean is expected!! Stored in my Useful file! Come to think of it, I use similar techniques in formulas all the time, but it never occurred to me to do the same in VBA.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry I guess didn't Explain it clearly.

I want to Keep Things hidden in my calculation file(parent file)but still use it in macro on it so those 9 files get pulled as new file.
And the NEW file which is generated, It pulls all the 9 hidden files from parent file (Cover+2 - 9). I want All 9 sheets Visible in NEW file, all the time So i can send them as report.  
And if someone want to see my parent file all the time i want them to see only calculation worksheet and not mess with other 9 hidden sheets(not want them to know about hidden files).My Macro does reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys 
I some how by trial and error and with your help figured it out. 
I just put .close thing which i saw somewhere on this group.

Here is the modified code based on all the suggestions. May have some unnecessary things but somehow it works.
Many Thanks to you all

```
Sub SaveMain()

Dim Flname As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next

Flname = "Pump Datasheet-" & InputBox("Enter Pump tag No P-XXXX:") & ".xls"

Sheets(Array("Cover", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")).Copy

newfilename = Flname

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=50
.Close 0
End With
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If ws.Name <> "Calculations" Then
 ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 End If

Next

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```